# mysql query conditional for selecting extra data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, conditional-statements

i have the following query im running, however if cid in sales table is not in the set of id's in the customer table, then the record doesn't show in the results.

is there a way to keep what i have working. so if a customer id is found then get the customer info, and if its not then name and phone return blank?

```
    $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.first_name,
                CONCAT(c.fname, ' ', c.lname) AS name, c.phone
                    FROM sales a, users b, customers c
                        WHERE a.cid = c.id  AND a.eid = b.id AND a.status = 0";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `left joins`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.first_name,
       CONCAT(c.fname, ' ', c.lname) AS name, c.phone
FROM sales a
INNER JOIN users b on a.eid = b.id
LEFT  JOIN customers c on a.cid = c.id
WHERE a.status = 0
```